# How can I remove automatic temperature adjustments in a house heating control panel?

Tags: heating

In a White Rodgers 1F87-361 house heating temperature controller there are several programs for automatically adjusting temperatures for several timings in each weekday. I was wondering how to remove all or some of the settings.

Starting on page 6 of [its manual](https://climate.emerson.com/documents/1f87-361-instructions-en-4209140.pdf), I don't find a way to disable or remove all or some setting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@PhilippNagel pointed out the hold function, which is fine if you want a constant temperature 24/7.

I think your question is more of having fewer than 4 periods per day. You cannot. What you can do is have two or more consecutive periods set the same temperature. This is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the thermostat to just hold a certain temperature and just ignore the day/time setting, you're looking for the HOLD feature. It is described on page 5 of the manual you linked:

```
HOLD TEMPERATURE — The thermostat can hold any
temperature within its range for an indefinite period without
reverting to the programmed temperature. Momentarily press
HOLD button. “HOLD” will be displayed. Then choose the
desired temperature by pressing [ARROW UP] or [ARROW DOWN]. The thermostat
will hold the room temperature at the selected setting until
you press RUN button to start program operation again.
```

If you're looking to revert everything to the factory settings, follow this procedure (page 7):

```
If a voltage spike or static discharge blanks out the display or
causes erratic thermostat operation you can reset the thermostat by pressing [ARROW UP] ,[ARROW DOWN] and TIME at the same time. This
also resets the factory defaults to the configuration menu and
TROUBLESHOOTING
program.
```